# How to integrate pinterest with android app

Tags: android, pinterest

I need to share some text and image from my android app to Pinterest, how could it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Pinterest's API is closed off, they don't document it, or give any explanation or way to register applications to be able to use it.

Basically, they don't want anyone but them making apps that interact with their site, while it's possible (you could, for instance, run a web browser in the background and have it open pages and such just as a user on the website would) it's not really 'meant' to be done, so it won't be easy :/